# PHP - UTF8 session polish characters

Tags: php, session

I do not know how to properly set charset in session - polish language, I have something like this  **usuniÄ�ty**. Thank you in advance for your help

### head file - list_photos_45.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

 <?php echo message(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**file - delete.php**

```
$_SESSION["message"] = "Ten produkt został usunięty.";
        redirect_to("list_photos_45.php");
```

---

**session**

```
<?php

  session_start();
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

  function message() {
    if (isset($_SESSION["message"])) {
      $output = "<div class=\"message\">";
      $output .= htmlentities($_SESSION["message"]);
      $output .= "</div>";

      // clear message after use
      $_SESSION["message"] = null;

      return $output;
    }
  }

  function errors() {
    if (isset($_SESSION["errors"])) {
      $errors = $_SESSION["errors"];

      // clear message after use
      $_SESSION["errors"] = null;

      return $errors;
    }
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `htmlentities()` on the message without also giving an encoding (third parameter). This is ISO-8859-1 by default in PHP < 5.4, and will convert every single byte of a multibyte charachter into it's maching entity, destroying the original character.

Best if you just use `htmlspecialchars()` instead. You are already using UTF-8, all you need now is escaping the characters that have special meaning in HTML to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: thank you very much - you're right $output .= htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["message"]);

Answer (score 1):

In your editor, make sure to save pages as UTF-8 without BOM (Byte order mark). Right now your pages are encoded as ANSI, and browser is reading them as UTF-8, so that is why you have bad characters.

EDIT: And you don't have to use htmlentities.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$con->set_charset("utf8");
```

and documentation
[mysqli_set_charset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)